# Deleting user properties on feature disable

Tags: my-site, user-profile-property

I'm making the creating of custom user properties automatically, so when the feature is activated the few user profiles properties will be created, how to do that i found on msdn (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms491835.aspx).

But now the real question how do i delete those properties on feature deactivated?
Beacause CoreProperty doesnt have the delete method.

Answer (score 1):

If i understood you clearly, [CorePropertyManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.server.userprofiles.corepropertymanager_members.aspx) have remove methods. You can use one of whem.

Comment: Oh you are right, RemovePropertyByName(), ty. But what if that property doesnt exist will it raise error

Comment: Might you use method CorePropertyManager.GetPropertyByName to check? If not, it might be helpfull to check It in CorePropertyManager.Properties ArrayList